# Use REST API to add item with specific ID to list

Tags: list, rest, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm creating a favoriting system, where each time a user favorites an item, an item in a secondary list is created with that item's ID number and the user's alias. On a separate page, I will use that list to get all the item IDs with that user's alias, and list each item.

Here I specify the URL for the list, and the ID and alias:

```
var apiUrl = webUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Favorites')";
var data = {
   'ID': itemID,
   'UserAlias': user.LoginName.split('\\')[1]
};
```

Here the API is called:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: apiUrl,
   headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
      "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
   },
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

However, Sharepoint returns error 400 (Bad Request) and the following message:

```
"The parameter ID does not exist in method GetByTitle"
```

How do I set the ID of the new item? And if that's not possible and I need to use a separate ID column, how can I retrieve items by the new column for deletion and listing?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by adding `/items` to the end of my URL, and adding the metadata type information.

e.g. `var apiUrl = webUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Favorites')/items";`

and

```
var data = {
  'ID': itemID,
  'UserAlias': user.LoginName.split('\\')[1],
  '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.FavoritesListItem" }
};
```